# Grails 2.4 upgrade duplicate filter name AssetPipelineFilter

Tags: grails, grails-2.4

I'm upgrading an application from Grails 2.3.3 to 2.4.4 and I've worked through the required changes. The grails compile command runs clean but I'm stuck on a couple of errors during run-app.

```
[ERROR] org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester [End event threw exception]
....
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Duplicate filter name [AssetPipelineFilter]
at org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml.addFilter(WebXml.java:243)
```

And then

```
[ERROR] org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig [Parse error in application web.xml file at file:/Users/greg/.grails/2.4.4/projects/MyApp/resources/web.xml]
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/Users/greg/.grails/2.4.4/projects/MyApp/resources/web.xml; lineNumber: 64; columnNumber: 14; Error at (64, 14) : Duplicate filter name [AssetPipelineFilter]
....
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Duplicate filter name [AssetPipelineFilter]
```

Comment: Can you post the contents of `/Users/greg/.grails/2.4.4/projects/MyApp/resources/web.xml`? It would appear that you have a filter defined in there that shouldn't be.

Comment: Yes, there are two <filter-name> definitions for AssetPipelineFilter in the .grails/.../web.xml file. I manually delete one and the run-app command re-generates this file with two.

Comment: Double check your BuildConfig.groovy and make sure you aren't including the plugin twice or something equally silly. Also check to make sure your project doesn't have a customized web.xml to start with.

Comment: Thanks. I have a single entry 'compile ":asset-pipeline:1.9.9"'. I'm upgrading this app from 2.3.3 and did have not used this plugin but it sounds like it's required for 2.4.4